# Why does the value document.lastModified alway change on internet pages where it is static in local

Tags: javascript, html

I saw that accessing the value of

```js
document.lastModified
```

is alway set up to the current date when i'm on an online website but it is static when i look at a static html file on my computer.

Do you know why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is a difference between resources and files. The user agent can only render resources. Resources may be, but do not have to be, based on files.

If a user agent renders a local file (via the `file` protocol) as a resource directly, the modified date is actually available from the filesystem and does not change until you modify the file.

If instead the resource is provided by a Web server (via HTTP), the user agent cannot know whether the resource is based on a file. The only explicit information that it has about the resource are the HTTP header, which may contain cache-controlling header fields such as `Last-Modified` that it can use, or the date from the local Web cache if the resource is retrieved from there instead.

In order to provide the most recent version, server software often sends a `Last-Modified` header field whose value is a date in the past or in the near future (from the time of retrieval), or an equivalent cache-controlling header field like `Cache-Control: …, max-age=0`. In that case, it is likely that the HTTP client will retrieve the resource from the original source instead of from the local Web cache because the version in the local cache is considered to be obsolete. Also, users may have disabled their Web cache (or configured it for short-term storage, or cleared it) or it was already full at the time of retrieval.

As a result, the value of the `lastModified` property often shows the date of last retrieval instead of the date of last modification of the content of the resource.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `document.lastModified` property is defined by the browser and refers to the document object model, as opposed to being defined by the file author and referring to its reference data on the server.